# Decent quality video hosting for China

Tags: video-quality

For most of the world, YouTube provides decent quality video hosting, and for those who want higher quality, there is Vimeo.

Unfortunately, practically all non-Chinese video hosting services are [blocked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Firewall) [in China](https://www.comparitech.com/privacy-security-tools/blockedinchina/), and all Chinese ones I tried compress videos to abysmal quality (in addition to watermarking it with their own name).

Are there any high-quality video hosting services that are accessible from China?

Comment: It wasn't clear to me if this question is on-topic here. If not, let me know and I will delete it.

Comment: Cloudflare recently started video distribution. In beta now, but take a look. https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-cloudflare-stream/

Comment: @Mulvya Thanks for the pointer, it looks interesting. But as far as I can tell, this is for people who are trying to set up their own integrated streaming, and are willing to pay for it. I am looking for something consumer-focused, suitable for a hobbyist: just like YouTube or Vimeo.  If I could find something that is as good in quality as YouTube, I would be very happy.  All Chinese services I tried (Bilibili, Youku, Tudou) look obviously worse than YouTube, not only for a trained eye, but for just about anyone looking at them.